# Android xml(layout) used by multiple activity in project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I am developing a project which has multiple activities and each activity sets values in `Textview`. Also I'm using same xml file containing multiple `Textviews` for all activities. I created multiple text view in one xml file.  I don't know how to kept value of one activity in text view as new activity started it reload xml again so old value gone.

My activity runs sequentially and I want that **if activity one set TCP Download(id)** and other **activity set TCP Upload(id)**, while **TCP Upload setting value TCP Download value should intake not disappear**

I want display value not vanished as new activity **setContentView(R.layout.main)** called it reload xml again and I want already set TextView value not disappear as intent pass to new activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@color/black"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tcpdownload1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="TCP Download: "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
 />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tcpdownload"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />  
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tcpupload1"
    android:text="TCP Upload: "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="16dip"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="120dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tcpupload"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="16dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tcprtt1"
    android:text="TCP RTT"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dip"/>

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="120dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tcprtt"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:textSize="16dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/packetloss1"
        android:text="Packet Loss"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="120dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/packetloss"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textSize="16dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity A set value of id1 and now **activity A --> activity B**, in activity B i want to set value of id2 but i also want id1 value in display

Comment: @reidzeibel that i already do i want display value not vanished as new activity setContentView(R.layout.main) called it reload xml again and i don't want this

Comment: seems like you need only one activity and you created some issues for you by creating multiple activities.. can it be done using single activity ?

Comment: @Akhil it will but create difficultly as my code line cross 10000LOC and each activity communicate to server for different purpose so one activity for one motive is suitable

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the `TextView` values while switching activities right??
You can save values in a sharedPref or simply hold values in a different class/model also you can pass values from one activity to other using `intent` for eg:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(contextInstance, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: that i already do, i want display value not vanished as new activity **setContentView(R.layout.main)** called it reload xml again and i don't want to vanish my already set TextView value from display

Comment: lets say your app flow is activity A --> activity B now you wants to reload all the values when you come back to Activity A from Activity B is that you want to achieve ??

Comment: nope i want this activity A set value of id1 and now activity A --> activity B, in activity B i want to set value of id2 but i also want id1 value in display

Comment: pass values from Activity A to B  and set it in textviews

Comment: i can do this but my problem is why reload same xml again in again in different activity as all activity used same file

Answer (score 0):

You can use String buffer to store value of TextView,

like this.

```
StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer();
TextView tcpdownload = (TextView)findViewByid(R.id.tcpdownload1);
String str = "as you want to set as text";
s1.append(str);
```

and display s1 when its relative activity opened.

```
tcpdownload.setText(s1.tostring());
```

do this for all activity.
Create different String-Buffer for different activity.

load them when new activity start respectively.

Comment: is there any better solution this as my xml file not changed(all activity call same  xml file) so not need to set id1 value again in activity2 as id1 already set by activity1

Comment: another solution is create string value in String.xml file like  `<string name = "download_1">Download 1</string>` and `<string name = "upload 1">upload_1</string>`  and try this to use as `tcpdownload.setText(R.string.download_1);` and in second activity find that TextView and set text as  `tcpdownload.setText(R.string.upload_1);`

Answer (score 0):

There are few points i will mention:

1. You can use the extra for intent when you are starting another activity to pass the value and get those value in destination activity and display in the textview. As shown below:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, Destination.class);
   intent.putExtra(key, value);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Or you can use the ShredPreference to store values. But it stores only premitive type and String. But it can avoid passing the same value(if you are using the same value) again and again.
3. 3rd approach which is not recommended that you can go for storing in the database. This will allow to modify the existing data very well.